# PySide6 QDockWidget Shadow disappears while using setTitleBarWidget

Tags: python, qt, shadow, pyside6

When Using setTitleBarWidget to remove native titlebar makes the box shadow of the QDockWidget disappear.
How to keep shadow effect?
(PySide6 version 6.3.1)

Comment: That's the expected behavior, as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget): "If a title bar widget is set, QDockWidget will not use native window decorations when it is floated."